# Unable to save all users into SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom, multiple-values, person-or-group

I am creating a list item using the code below:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
var dfd = $.Deferred(); 
var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
context.load(targetList); 
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
var listItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

listItem.set_item("Title", listValues[0].Title); 
listItem.set_item("Department", listValues[0].Department);  
listItem.set_item("TeamMembers", listValues[0].TeamMembers);
listItem.set_item("Notes", listValues[0].Notes);  
listItem.update();
context.executeQueryAsync( 
    function () { 
        var id = listItem.get_id();
        if (listValues[0].Files.length > 0) {   
             if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length - 1) {                 
                 loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck).then( 
                 function () { }, 
                 function (sender, args) { 
                     dfd.reject(sender, args); 
                 } ); 
            } 
        } 
        else { dfd.resolve(fileCountCheck);             } 
    }, 
    function (sender, args) {       }   );
```

TeamMembers is a string containing the UserIds of all the users selected in a people picker, in the format `;#564;#5454;#56;#865;#`

It is working if only one person is selected.
I noticed that when there are multiple users selected, many of them are not getting saved into the list.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/2c113538-cbbf-4337-8cf5-9c406f9012cb/add-multiple-people-using-javascript-client-object-model) if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap, that really helped.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have added it as an answer below with explanation and reference link. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @Ganesh Sanap, I changed the data passed into the user field as below:

`TeamMembers` now has a value in the format `";#" + this.user1.get_id() + ";#" + this.user1.get_loginName() + ";" + this.user2.get_id() + ";#" + this.user2.get_loginName()`.

With the latest format, I am able to successfully save all the usernames into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing only User IDs in `TeamMembers`, try passing the User ID as well as User Login name separated `;#` (And multiple users separated by `;`) like below:

```
var userField = this.user1.get_id() + ";#" + this.user1.get_loginName()+";"+this.user2.get_id() + ";#" + this.user2.get_loginName(); // and so on...
listItem.set_item('TeamMembers', userField);
listItem.Update();
```

**Reference**: [Add multiple people using Javascript Client Object Model](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/2c113538-cbbf-4337-8cf5-9c406f9012cb/add-multiple-people-using-javascript-client-object-model).